# customizing footnotes

Tags: footnotes

There is a spacing difference (both vertical and horizontal) between using

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\wackyfn}[1]{\expandafter\@wackyfn\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\@wackyfn}[1]{\ifcase#1\or*\or$\spadesuit$\else\@ctrerr\fi}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\wackyfn{footnote}}
\makeatother
```

and

```
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

which seems the proper way to do things: is it possible to have something close to the second command, but which is also able to have footnotes with $\spadesuit$ etc. instead of * and similar, keeping the correct spacing and dimensions?

A complete example is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\wackyfn}[1]{\expandafter\@wackyfn\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand*{\@wackyfn}[1]{\ifcase#1\or*\or$\spadesuit$\else\@ctrerr\fi }
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\wackyfn{footnote}}
\makeatother

Wrong\footnote{footnote}, compare to Wrong$^*$

\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

Right\footnote{footnote2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

```
\or * \or
```

defines that value to be a `*` followed by a space you want

```
\or *\or
```

similarly the other cases.

Comment: thanks for the answer; eliminating the spaces as you suggest gives the correct horizontal spacing, but vertically it is higher compared to standard footnote or $^*$

Comment: @jj_p the standard fnsymbol command does nothing about vertical spacing (or the font size) it just uses its collection of symbols dagger etc, perhaps you have chosen taller symbols in your list

Comment: @jj_p questions should _always_ have a complete (`\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) example document so that people can test their answers and see what you are seeing, edit your question with an example usage showing the height difference.

Comment: done, I added a complete example

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand my problem: I'm missing `\ensuremath` inside

```
\newcommand*{\@wackyfn}[1]\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or*\or\spadesuit\else\@ctrerr\fi}}
```

Comment: This is a rather a comment or add-on to your original question than an answer.

Comment: well, adding that solves the issue; it's a bit funny answering one's own questions, but that's what I needed

Comment: You can just use `$*$` as well...

Comment: right, the point is that $*$ and * give different vertical alignments, and that was my problem (of course, \ensuremath is the same as $$ for all the symbols)